# Linked list example using threads

Tags: winapi, multithreading, synchronization, linked-list

I have read the following code of using `CRITICAL_SECTION` when working with multiple threads to grow a linked list. what would be the main() part which uses two threads to add to linked list?

```
#include <windows.h>

typedef struct _Node
{
    struct _Node *next;
    int data;
} Node;

typedef struct _List
{
    Node *head;
    CRITICAL_SECTION critical_sec;
} List;

List *CreateList()
{
    List *pList = (List*)malloc(sizeof(pList));
    pList->head = NULL;
    InitializeCriticalSection(&pList->critical_sec);
    return pList;
}

void AddHead(List *pList, Node *node)
{
    EnterCriticalSection(&pList->critical_sec);
    node->next = pList->head;
    pList->head = node;
    LeaveCriticalSection(&pList->critical_sec);
}

void Insert(List *pList, Node *afterNode, Node *newNode)
{
    EnterCriticalSection(&pList->critical_sec);
    if (afterNode == NULL)
    {
        AddHead(pList, newNode);
    }
    else
    {
        newNode->next = afterNode->next;
        afterNode->next = newNode;
    }
    LeaveCriticalSection(&pList->critical_sec);
}

Node *Next(List *pList, Node *node)
{
    Node* next;
    EnterCriticalSection(&pList->critical_sec);
    next = node->next;
    LeaveCriticalSection(&pList->critical_sec);
    return next;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will likely involve one or more calls to [CreateThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682453(VS.85).aspx)